# Issue with passing a matrix into a function

Tags: c++

what can I do... I need to pass a matrix into the function?

```
error C2664: 'WriteMatrixOut' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [480][640]' to 'char ** '
```

Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

```
class Image 
{
public:
    char mm[480][640];
    void WriteMatrixOut(char **mm);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare it as `void WriteMatrixOut(char mm[480][640]);` instead.

Comment: You may declare parameter like this `char mm[][640]`. It's also possible

Comment: Yappie's comment illustrates why this is not a type-safe way to declare this argument. If you want some more type safety, you can use `void WriteMatrixOut(char (&mm)[480][640]);` This is a reference to an array with exactly these dimensions, and the compiler will check this when calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

`char**` and `char[x][y]` are fundamentally different and cannot be cast.

When you do `char array[100][100]`, the compiler will allocate everything in one place, with no pointers involved at all. It is equivalent too:

`typedef char innerArray[100]; innerArray mm[100];`

So it is 100 chunks of 100 chars each. `sizeof(mm)` will be a 10,000 bytes, and you would have better luck casting mm to `char*` than `char**`.

However, if you dynamically allocate an array of arrays by using `char**`, you have one pointer to an contiguous array of pointers; these pointers reference arbitrary locations in memory that have an arbitrary length each. (This also allows you to have jagged arrays.) These two memory layouts are really completely different.

Now, you could be tempted to just use the same type in the argument declaration:

```
char mm[100][100];
void writeMatrixOut(char mm[100][100]);
```

But this is not safe because C makes the issue even more confusing. `foo(int x[3])`, `foo(int x[])` and `foo(int *x)` are all equivalent. I am not sure how this works with nested arrays, but at least one array dimension will not be checked by the compiler when you pass an argument.

You can avoid this with a typedef:

```
typedef char Matrix[100][100];
Matrix mm;
void writeMatrixOut(Matrix &mm); // might even be 'const Matrix &'
```

But even then, you cannot assign or return arrays. To make arrays behave, you have to wrap them in a struct or class:

```
struct Matrix { char elements[100][100]; }
Matrix mm;
void writeMatrixOut(Matrix &mm); // might even be 'const Matrix &'
```

C++03/C++11 also contains an array<> wrapper class that can do this for you, but it is a bit unwieldy with nested arrays:

```
// namespace std::tr1:: in C++03, std:: in C++11
typedef array<100, array<100, char>> Matrix;
```